# Trouble with for loop in a function and combing multiple series output

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I'm new to python and am struggling to figure something out. I'm doing some data analysis on an invoice database in pandas with columns of $ amounts, credits, date, and a unique company ID for each package bought.

I want to run every unique company id through a function that will calculate the average spend rate of these credits based on the difference of package purchase dates.  I have the basics figured out in my function, and it returns a series indexed to the original dataframe with the values of the average amount of credits spent each day between packages. However, I only have it working with one company ID at a time, and I don'tknow what kind of process I can do to combine all of these different series for each company id to be able to correctly add a new column onto my dataframe with this average credit spend value for each package. Here's my code so far:

```
def creditspend(mylist = []):
    for i in mylist:        
        a = df.loc[df['CompanyId'] == i]
        a = a.sort_values(by=['Date'], ascending=False)
        days = a.Date.diff().map(lambda x: abs(x.days))
        spend = a['Credits']/days        
    print(spend)
```

If I call

```
creditspend(mylist=[8, 15])
```

(with multiple inputs) it obviously does not work. What do I need to do to complete this function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DO NOT use list as an argument. Read https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/

Comment: It would be easier if you gave us a code to create a sample df.

Answer (score 0):

apply() is a very useful method in pandas that applies a function to every row or column of a DataFrame.

So, if your DataFrame is `df`:

```
def creditspend(row):
    # some calculation code here
    return spend

df['spend_rate'] = df.apply(creditspend)
```

(You can also use apply() on columns with the axis=1 keyword.)

Comment: That doesn't really work for me here, because I need to group invoices by the unique company ID and only apply the function within that grouping, hence the for loop.

Comment: Ah, in that case, any time you want to group X by Y in pandas you want groupby().

`df.groupby("CompanyID").apply(func)` does work as well. It's a little less intuitive, unfortunately, because you get the whole group as a dataframe as the argument to the function with that apply(), but you should be able to do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a `groupby` for a *CompanyID* aggregation. Below demonstrates with random data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(7182018)
df = pd.DataFrame({'CompanyID': np.random.choice(['julia', 'pandas', 'r', 'sas', 'stata', 'spss'],50),
                   'Date': np.random.choice(pd.Series(pd.date_range('2018-01-01', freq='D', periods=180)), 50),
                   'Credits': np.random.uniform(0,1000,50)
                  }, columns=['Date', 'CompanyID', 'Credits'])

# SORT ONCE OUTSIDE OF PROCESSING
df = df.sort_values(by=['CompanyID', 'Date'], ascending=[True, False]).reset_index(drop=True)

def creditspend(g):          
    g['days'] = g.Date.diff().map(lambda x: abs(x.days))
    g['spend'] = g['Credits']/g['days']

    return g

grp_df = df.groupby('CompanyID').apply(creditspend)
```

**Output**

```
print(grp_df.head(20))

#          Date CompanyID     Credits  days       spend
# 0  2018-06-20     julia  280.522287   NaN         NaN
# 1  2018-06-12     julia  985.009523   8.0  123.126190
# 2  2018-05-17     julia  892.308179  26.0   34.319545
# 3  2018-05-03     julia   97.410360  14.0    6.957883
# 4  2018-03-26     julia  480.206077  38.0   12.637002
# 5  2018-03-07     julia   78.892365  19.0    4.152230
# 6  2018-03-03     julia  878.671506   4.0  219.667877
# 7  2018-02-25     julia  905.172807   6.0  150.862135
# 8  2018-02-19     julia  970.016418   6.0  161.669403
# 9  2018-02-03     julia  669.073067  16.0   41.817067
# 10 2018-01-23     julia  636.926865  11.0   57.902442
# 11 2018-01-11     julia  790.107486  12.0   65.842291
# 12 2018-06-16    pandas  639.180696   NaN         NaN
# 13 2018-05-21    pandas  565.432415  26.0   21.747401
# 14 2018-04-22    pandas  145.232115  29.0    5.008004
# 15 2018-04-13    pandas  379.964557   9.0   42.218284
# 16 2018-04-12    pandas  538.168690   1.0  538.168690
# 17 2018-03-20    pandas  783.572993  23.0   34.068391
# 18 2018-03-14    pandas  618.354489   6.0  103.059081
# 19 2018-02-10    pandas  859.278127  32.0   26.852441
```

Comment: This seems like a great solution. When I tried to implement it, though, I get 

    `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'days'`

Comment: Please post a sample of your data and `dtypes`. It seems your *date* may not be a date time.

Comment: The data you used is effectively identical to mine. The date is a datetime, I converted it with dt.date method. I get timedeltas in days with no problem when passing through a company ID in my original function.

Comment: I think the issue is in the lambda function, but changing it to 

`lambda x: abs(int(x.days))`

returned the same error.

Comment: Are you getting an error with this solution which you should be able to copy/paste directly and run in empty Python environment? I use Python 3.4/pandas 0.23.

Comment: I ran this

`df1['Days'] = df1.Date.diff().map(lambda x: abs(x.days))`

after sorting by id and date and it worked great. My only problem now is I have to make the value of Days NaN for the first occurrence of each id. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: I do not understand. Other than your new item, what was the original problem described above?